# Am I entitled to a UK state pension?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

I worked from 1979 to 1989 in the UK before moving abroad in 1990. The UK gov website doesn’t recognize my  National Insurance (NINO) number and since I turned 65 this year I was wondering if I was entitled to a pension?

Answer (score 2):

You’ll usually need to have 10 qualifying years on your National Insurance record to get any new State Pension. To resolve the issue with your NINO you can

- [contact National Insurance general enquiries](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/hm-revenue-customs/contact/national-insurance-enquiries-for-employees-and-individuals) and/or
- apply for a [National Insurance statement](https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/gg/sign-in) from HM Revenue and Customs (HMRC) to check if your record has gaps

If you still live abroad, you might also be able to submit a claim using the [International State Pension claim form](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-claiming-a-state-pension-if-you-retire-abroad)

Comment: There may very well be rules for people who made state pension contributions in different EU countries.